# Deleting " character from listview VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv, import

I am importing a CSV file into a listview.

[imported csv in listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Eeg.png)

[csv is looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPog2.png)

```
   Dim CSVTest As New List(Of String)
    ListView1.Clear()

    ' Opent bestandselectie.
    Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    ' Test of de file corect is geimporteerd.
    If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Captured de /path.
        Dim CSVFile As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        ' Set path als bronbestand
        CSVTest = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFile).ToList


        'Voegt de headers van de data toe
        Dim ColNames As List(Of ColumnHeader) = New List(Of ColumnHeader)


        Dim ColumnArray() As String = CSVTest(0).Split(";")

        For i = 0 To ColumnArray.Count - 1

            ColNames.Add(New ColumnHeader)
            ColNames(i).Name = ColumnArray(i)
            ColNames(i).Text = ColumnArray(i)

        Next
        ListView1.Columns.AddRange(ColNames.ToArray)

        'Voegt de rijen met data toe
        For I = 1 To CSVTest.Count - 1
            Dim col() As String = CSVTest(I).Split(";")
            Dim NewLVItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(col(0))
            NewLVItem.Name = col(0)
            For j = 1 To col.Count - 1
                NewLVItem.SubItems.Add(col(j))
            Next
            ListView1.Items.Add(NewLVItem)
        Next
    End If
```

Does anyone know how i am able to remove the " characters without editing the CSV file first? (as the csv is exported from an inventory system)

Comment: Don't read the file using `File.ReadAllLines` and `String.Split`. Use a `TextFieldParser`. It will automatically deal with field values in quotes. The point of quoting field values is to allow delimiters within data, which your method of reading won't allow for. The `TextFieldParser` class understands these CSV formatting rules and will accommodate them properly. The class documentation includes a code example, so you should read that. You should always read the documentation for new classes anyway, but people rarely do. Even when I tell them to, they still often don't. You should read it.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, i will definitely read the documentation then and figure it out. Thankyou again!

Comment: If you don't like TFP there are probably a hundred other CSV libraries you can try.. Search nuget.org for CSV..